# Songs that end on the leading tone?

Tags: theory, pop-music

I'm looking for songs (mainly pop songs) that end their melody on the leading tone. I'm struggling to come up with any off the top of my head, can anyone help out?

Comment: Presumably the last chord would then be major 7th, rather than the dominant?

Comment: Probably you won't find tunes but there are arrangements with the major seventh: https://www.google.com/search?q=where+you+there+ny+staffband&oq=where+you+there+ny+staffband&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160l2.22468j1j7&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:89c71280,vid:wdbFdfoZu2I

Comment: There's the intro to The Sound of Music's Doh Re Mi, but it only pauses, it doesn't end there [of course it ends by over-cooking, rinse/repeating the idea until the least musical child in the audience gets a clue ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin (and ultimately ends with Julie Andrews belting “Dooooooooooo!”)

Comment: Arguably not part of the melody, but for finishing on the leading note I think the definitive piece must be **the original _Muppet Show_ closing theme**! (And you've no idea just how often I'm tempted to end other songs the same way…)